# Greatest two rows in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

If this is my pandas DataFrame:

```
rand = np.random.RandomState(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['comp1', 'comp2'] * 9,
                   'B': ['user1', 'user2','user3'] * 6,
                   'C': rand.randn(18)})

    A   B   C
0   comp1   user1   1.624345
1   comp2   user2   -0.611756
2   comp1   user3   -0.528172
3   comp2   user1   -1.072969
4   comp1   user2   0.865408
5   comp2   user3   -2.301539
6   comp1   user1   1.744812
7   comp2   user2   -0.761207
8   comp1   user3   0.319039
9   comp2   user1   -0.249370
10  comp1   user2   1.462108
11  comp2   user3   -2.060141
12  comp1   user1   -0.322417
13  comp2   user2   -0.384054
14  comp1   user3   1.133769
15  comp2   user1   -1.099891
16  comp1   user2   -0.172428
17  comp2   user3   -0.877858
```

I'd like to run a pandas command to return the same form of result set but showing only the two greatest values of C for each combination of A and B.

I know I can sort by A and B in ascending order and then by C in descending order by using this:

```
df.sort_index(by = ['A','B','C'],ascending=[True,True,False])
```

and then I think I need to use the groupby to show only the two greatest values of C. Closest I can get is showing the greatest and smallest values by using first() and last()

```
df.sort_index(by = ['A','B','C'],ascending=[True,True,False]).groupby(['A','B']).first()
df.sort_index(by = ['A','B','C'],ascending=[True,True,False]).groupby(['A','B']).last()
```

Problem is I'm after the greatest 2 (or in general, greatest x) plus I want the same form of final result set as my original DataFrame.

Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to add another column to the data frame that will show only which `C` values are the highest in their group? If I'm correct you can do it using a `groupby` and then iterating through each group, sorting by `C` values and using the index of the highest 2 values in the sorted group to set the value of the `D` column to `True`:

```
df['D'] = False
grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
for grouer, group in grouped:
    df.ix[group.sort_index(by='C')[-2:].index, 'D'] = True
```

This will produce:

```
        A      B         C      D
0   comp1  user1  1.624345   True
1   comp2  user2 -0.611756   True
2   comp1  user3 -0.528172  False
3   comp2  user1 -1.072969   True
4   comp1  user2  0.865408   True
5   comp2  user3 -2.301539  False
6   comp1  user1  1.744812   True
7   comp2  user2 -0.761207  False
8   comp1  user3  0.319039   True
9   comp2  user1 -0.249370   True
10  comp1  user2  1.462108   True
11  comp2  user3 -2.060141   True
12  comp1  user1 -0.322417  False
```

If on the other hand you want to filter out just the highest `C` values into a new DataFrame, then do:

```
indexes = []
grouped = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
for grouer, group in grouped:
    indexes.extend(group.sort_index(by='C')[-2:].index)
df.iloc[indexes, :]
```

Which will filter out just the highest two in every group, giving you:

```
        A      B         C
0   comp1  user1  1.624345
6   comp1  user1  1.744812
4   comp1  user2  0.865408
10  comp1  user2  1.462108
8   comp1  user3  0.319039
14  comp1  user3  1.133769
3   comp2  user1 -1.072969
9   comp2  user1 -0.249370
1   comp2  user2 -0.611756
13  comp2  user2 -0.384054
11  comp2  user3 -2.060141
17  comp2  user3 -0.877858
```

Comment: Thanks, Viktor. Yes, I was after the highest two in every group.